# How can I open .DB7 data files?

Tags: import, nexusdb

I've got a bunch of files with DB7 extension, coming from a customer's software.
Each one of them is related to a database table.
What I want is to export data in a more practical format, such as CSV.

Reading the header of the file, something addressed me to NexusDB, but I can't manage opening these files. Do you have any suggestions about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows and have Microsoft Access, you can download the [NexusDB ODBC driver](http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=node/528) and create a linked table in Access.  You can then use Access to export to CSV.